# codespaces dockerfile copy fails

Tags: docker, codespaces, github-codespaces

I am trying to learn codespaces and I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:debian-11

RUN apt update -y; \
    apt install python3-pip -y

COPY .devcontainer/req.txt /usr/local/bin/.
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/bin/req.txt
```

but bizzarely the copy always seem to fails with this error:

```
#9 ERROR: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3300366747/.devcontainer: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3300366747/.devcontainer: no such file or directory
```

What is going on? I am baffled!

When I look at the rescue container, I do see the file intact under `.devcontainer`

my tree is lie so:

```
-src
    -.devcontainer
        -Dockerfile
        - devcontainer.json
        - req.txt
    - main.py
```

and in my devcontainer.json, I have:

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/debian
{
    "name": "Debian",
    // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
    // "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:${templateOption:imageVariant}"
    "build": {
        // Path is relataive to the devcontainer.json file.
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    }
    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    // "features": {},

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    // "customizations": {},

    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "root"
}
```

Comment: Is there a directory named `.devcontainer` in your build context (ie in the same directory where your dockerfile lies) which contains a file named `req.txt`?

Comment: @derpirscher I have updated the post with my dir tree and the json. I think it is in the build context because it is picking the Dockerfile?

Comment: No, it's not. because your `Dockerfile` is *inside*  the `.devcontainer` directory ...

Comment: @derpirscher oh? so what is the fix?

Comment: either just do `COPY req.txt /usr/local/bin` or move your dockerfile one directory up ...

Comment: @derpirscher oh actually.. the problem was that I was copyng to `/local/bin` but was tring to install from `/bin/req.txt`. so stupid of me. Thank you again

Comment: That may have been an addtional problem in the next step. But the problem you posted here was, that it couldn't find a `.devcontainer` directory in the docker build context

Comment: @derpirscher yes your right, if you could post that as a silution, id be happy to accept it :) thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your posted directory structure, I see that your `Dockerfile` is actually *inside* the `.devcontainer` directory you are referring to in your `COPY` command. That's not allowed, so either

- Change your command to `COPY req.txt /usr/local/bin/`

or

- Move your `Dockerfile` one directory up and call `docker build` from there (note, that moving your docker file may break other steps of your build chain)